# Join 3 mySQL tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've spent last hours trying to find out how to generate an appropiate MySQL query to access my data. This is my sql table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clip` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `clip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
)
```

I have minimized tables as much as possible. *record* table contains client data, then *clip* is used to join this client with some client parameters that are stored in *data*. Each client may have as much *record*'s as he wants and each record is composed by an undetermined number of *clip*s. Then, each *clip* references to some *data* values.

Ok, the query I'm looking for is one that given a *sheet*, a *data* *name* and a *value* it gets the last (*date*) *client*s that accomplishes the condition *name*=*given_name* AND *value*=*given_value*. It is, I'm looking for the clients that accomplishes that condition in the LAST record stored in the database.

I've arrived to this sentence:

```
SELECT client
FROM clip, record 
WHERE clip.id IN (SELECT clip FROM `data` WHERE name='level' AND value='2')
```

But it returns all clients, not only the last ones and all my tests including *date* have been unsuccessful.

**EDIT**: After some try-and-error and thanks to the ideas you gave me, I've arrived to a query that seems to work, but it is really complex and I'm quite sure you can help me to simplify:

```
SELECT * FROM clip, data
WHERE data.clip=clip.id 
 AND record IN (SELECT id
  FROM record a
  WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM record b
    WHERE a.client = b.client
    )
 )
 AND data.name='NAME_HERE' AND data.value='VALUE_HERE'
```

Well, that's not exactly what I want, I need the client ID, but it gives me the last record for this client that is enough for me.

Comment: select **id** from record table also

Comment: you can post your solution as an Answer and mark it as correct, it helps clear out questions that have already been answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your quesiton correctly then see if this works for you:

```
SELECT client
FROM record, clip, data
WHERE name = "given_name" AND value = "given_value"
AND data.clip = clip.id
AND clip.record = record.id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Updated query based on your comments:

```
SELECT client, MAX(date)
FROM record, clip, data
WHERE name = "given_name" AND value = "given_value"
AND data.clip = clip.id
AND clip.record = record.id
GROUP BY client
```

It was helpful that you have posted some data and the output required from it. I have updated the query below:

```
SELECT record.client
FROM clip JOIN data ON (data.clip = clip.id)
JOIN record ON (clip.record = record.id)
JOIN (
   SELECT client, MAX(date) as date
   FROM record
   GROUP BY client
) AS r ON (r.client = record.client AND r.date = record.date)
WHERE name = "given_name" AND value = "given_value"
```

Comment: The LIMIT is cuting the output, returning only one client, but a lot of clients could accomplish the condition. If you modify this to set a DISTINCT and remove the LIMIT is still a problem: the query is returning "old" records (i.e. if the client sets a value, and then sets another value, this query not only returns the client ID if it is set the last one, it returns it always). Sorry.

Comment: This second query has the same problem than the first. Imagine you have some data for the client 1 like this: a record with this value {1,1,1/1/2011}, a clip with this {1,1,1} and a data with {1,a,b}. Ok, then I add another record={2,1,10/8/2011}, clip={2,2,2} and data={2,a,c}. Then if I ask for the last clients that accomplish the condition a=b (name=a and value=b), your query returns that client 1 has an 'a' variable with value 'b', but that's not true due it has changed it and now a=c (date 10/8/2011 is later than 1/1/2011).

Comment: Please check my latest edit, it would also give you the client id. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Great! It has best performance than my first solution. Only one question: SELECT client produces a ambiguos result. It must be SELECT record.client

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT data.name,data.value,record.client FROM data
 JOIN clip on clip.id = data.clip
 JOIN record ON record.id = clip.record WHERE data.name = 'name' AND data.value = 'value' ORDER BY record.date DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: That has exactly the same problem as the first @Aziz Shaikh answer: it returns all clients that have had a pair {name,value} anytime.See my comment to the Aziz answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've found, perhaps it could be optimized, but this needs other question:

```
SELECT * FROM clip, data
WHERE data.clip=clip.id 
 AND record IN (SELECT id
  FROM record a
  WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM record b
    WHERE a.client = b.client
    )
 )
 AND data.name='NAME_HERE' AND data.value='VALUE_HERE'
```